# meaning of 'By Way Of Deception, Thou Shalt Do War'

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar

Mossad used to have the motto "בתחבולות תעשה לך מלחמה". One former Mossad officer [claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/By_Way_of_Deception) that this motto means:

> By Way Of Deception, Thou Shalt Do War

What does this mean?

I know it is about false flag, but I don't know these archaic English words.

Comment: By using deception you will fight

Comment: @sumelic: It's a fake translation. (The actual motto was from Proverbs 24:6; the KJV translates it as "by wise counsel thou shalt make thy war".) But I don't think that affects the question very much.

Comment: Voting to close, since your real question seems to be "What do *thou* and *shalt* mean?", which can easily be answered by looking them up in a dictionary.

Comment: @ruakh: In his book titled "By Way of Deception: The Making and Unmaking of a Mossad Officer", Victor Ostrovsky mentionned that the Mossad academy director told him that the Mossad motto was "Deceit is essential in warfare", not exactly the Bible quote.

Comment: sounds like **Art of War**, which states that war is based on deception

Comment: Maybe move it to Linguistics SE, where there are many Hebrew speakers.

Answer (score 1):

The archaic part is just the second person singular of 'shall'

> I shall
>   Thou shalt  (nowadays you shall)
>   He/she/it shall ...

Grizzly gives a good paraphrase in a comment: "By using deception you will fight"

Reversing that gives:  "**You will fight by using deception.**"

---

**Note**

The question refers to a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/By_Way_of_Deception). There appear to be several unsubstantiated claims in the article.

For example the Hebrew text that is quoted

בתחבולות תעשה לך מלחמה

when [cut and pasted into Google translate](https://translate.google.co.uk/#iw/en/%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%91%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D7%9A%20%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%94) gives "Deceit is essential in warfare"  Note that automatic translators can be unreliable. It is even possible that (as  ruakh points out in a comment) a person unknown has deliberately mistranslated the phrase.  I don't know Hebrew so I can't speak on this.

Was this Hebrew text ever actually the motto of Mossad? Why, according to Wikipedia is its supposed translation  "for by wise counsel though shalt do war"?

Here is the actual Biblical text according to [BibleHub.com](http://biblehub.com/text/proverbs/24-6.htm):

[image]

The [literal translation of that (according to Bible Hub)](http://biblehub.com/text/proverbs/24-6.htm) is "for by wise you shall make to you war"

My conclusion is that the Wiki article, and probably this whole subject, should be treated with scepticism all round.

If anyone wishes me to improve this answer please feel free to offer suggestions. However, if you do have any suggestions please back them up with authentic facts from a properly documented source.

Comment: Regarding your "however" . . . I don't think anyone can possibly dispute that "בתחבולות תעשה לך מלחמה" means "with *takhbulot* you shall make war". So the Google Translate "translation" is obviously not the result of applying an independent algorithm on the Hebrew; rather, Google Translate's bilingual corpus must include an instance of the entire phrase "בתחבולות תעשה לך מלחמה" translated as "Deceit is essential in warfare". So all this tells us is that some unknown-to-us source has translated it that way; which is not really useful information.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: My comment was not about the goodness of the translation, but about its provenance. You say that you "clearly stated the source", but that's not really true; you attributed it to an obviously-unbiased machine translation service, but it's obvious that it must actually have come from some other source whose biases we don't know. (Not your fault, of course; you didn't know enough Hebrew to tell this. But now that you do know, you should edit your answer to fix or remove the misleading attribution.)

Comment: I don't know any Hebrew. I don't know if  you know any Hebrew. Maybe you do. If you are an authority on translating Hebrew into English and you can better translate the phrase, please say so.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: l wouldn't call myself "an authority on translating Hebrew into English", but yes, I know Hebrew; and I've already explained why the last part of your answer is misleading. (And Graffito, in a comment above, hammers home the point by identifying the true source of your translation.) You already have enough information to fix the problem I pointed out; you don't need me to "better translate the phrase" for you, because the problem isn't with the translation, but with the attribution.

Comment: @ruakh: Google Translate translates "בתחבולות" by itself as "trickery," so it is not a case of the entire phrase being translated as a whole (in terms of the connotation given to *takhbulot*).

Comment: @ruakh: This [dictionary](http://www.morfix.co.il/בתחבולות) defines *takhbulah* as "trick, ruse, stratagem." And in this page of [translations in context](http://context.reverso.net/translation/hebrew-english/בתחבולות), it seems to mostly have a negative context such as "wiles," "tricks," guile." Perhaps the connotations are different for Biblical and modern Hebrew? [Edit: never mind, I see that you got into that already in the comments below your answer. Maybe you should delete your apparently-incorrect comments above regarding the source of Google's translation?]

Comment: Does anyone here know for certain what the motto of Mossad actually was and what language it was in? Was it in modern Hebrew, Biblical Hebrew?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: I don't think you can tell the difference; generally the spelling (and modern pronunciation) is the same. I vaguely remember reading a story about someone finding it funny to hear a talk in Hebrew where a person used a form of the term "zayin," which classically meant "arms/weapons," but colloquially now means "penis." (I might have garbled this a little, but I think the basic idea is right.) ([source](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4027))

Comment: I accept that the meaning of words can change. However, the Hebrew quoted in the Wiki article is not precisely the same as the Hebrew from Proverbs. I have demonstrated that. Either Mossad rewrote the  Biblical phrase or that wasn't their motto.  Until someone proves what the motto was there's no point in translating it.

Comment: What is the difference? The wiki article quote you list first just seems to be contained perfectly in the BibleText quote you give. I see no difference in wording.

Comment: Although there is one difference in the punctuation: the use of this character: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_punctuation#Hyphen_and_maqaf

Comment: @sumelic: I didn't post any answer here, but if you're referring to my comments below *deadrat's* answer, then -- which of my comments is "apparently-incorrect"? I stand by my statement that Google Translate is *not* capable of translating "ב... תעשה לך מלחמה" as "... is essential to warfare", so if it translates "בתחבולות תעשה לך מלחמה" as "deceit is essential to warfare", then that translation must have come wholesale from the bilingual corpus it used, rather than being machine-generated. And Graffito, in a comment above, proves this, by providing a prior source of that translation.

Comment: Re: "Does anyone here know for certain what the motto of Mossad actually was and what language it was in? Was it in modern Hebrew, Biblical Hebrew?": There seems to be no dispute that its motto was "בתחבולות תעשה לך מלחמה" (from Proverbs 24:6), which is Biblical Hebrew, and not idiomatic in Modern Hebrew. However, in Hebrew as in English, old quotations are often taken out of context and repurposed (e.g. "Wherefore art thou Romeo?" taken to mean "Where are you, Romeo?"), so the meaning in the Bible is not *necessarily* the meaning that Mossad was going for.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's not the motto of the Mossad, the Israel secret service.  There are no "ancient english [sic] words" in your quote; they are a mistranslation of Biblical Hebrew.  The Hebrew that used to surround the original seal of the organization was from *[Proverbs](http://biblehub.com/proverbs/24-6.htm)* 24:6:

> For by wise guidance you will wage war

A former Mossad agent, Victor Ostrovsky, wrote a book called *By Way of Deception*, critical of his former employer.  Ostrovsky's translation uses the word *deception*, and this has been taken up by various antisemites to buttress their various claims of various Jewish cabals.

The Mossad is a clandestine organization, and they no doubt use deception in their work.  But a *false flag operation* is one in which an agency's operators seek to convince people that someone other than the agency was responsible.  In 1960, the Mossad was responsible for kidnapping Adolph Eichmann and in 1980 for killing the head of the Iraqi nuclear weapons program.  The Mossad tends to leave little evidence of their involvement in these kinds of actions, but no one would believe any country other than Israel carried them out, so the Mossad doesn't try to shift the responsibility.

Comment: This answer is correct, but it doesn't actually answer the OP's question. (After all, a question about "What does X mean?" is equally valid no matter who said X.)

Comment: @ruakh - Is the answer correct? I'm not sure that the statement  'they are a mistranslation of Biblical Hebrew' is true for the reasons I gave in my answer.   However I agree this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @deadrat - If you are going to quote Wikipedia verbatim then I think you need to (a) make it clear which are your words and which are by someone else and (b) acknowledge the source. Otherwise it's just plagiarism.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: I think the answer is correct, yes, albeit incomplete. Seemingly all Bible translations use "wise counsel" or similar. However, my dictionaries of *Modern* Hebrew (as used in Israel today) indicate that *takhbula* now has a range of meanings along the lines of "device, ruse, wile, strategy, trick". I honestly don't know quite what meaning Mossad intended, as a modern-day organization using this Bible quote as their motto. But it's perfectly reasonable to point out that this isn't he accepted meaning of the Bible quote.

Comment: I don't believe that you or anyone who has contributed so far  (including me) knows what the 'right' answer is concerning the actual motto and where it came from or what it is really supposed to mean. I made my uncertainty clear in the note below my answer.

Comment: What you "believe" is irrelevant.  The Hebrew that used to circumscribe the seal is the Hebrew from *Psalm 24*.  No standard English translation of the Psalm predating the Mossad uses the word *deception*.  I suppose no one can "really" know what the Mossad (or the officials of the Mossad who approved the design of the seal) "really" meant.

Comment: You say, "The Hebrew that used to circumscribe the seal is the Hebrew from Psalm 24."  What you fail to show is what that text actually is. Is it the text quoted in the Wiki article? If so that is not identical to the Biblical text.  A modern translation of modern Hebrew is going to be different from a modern translation of Biblical Hebrew.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: To reiterate: the text quoted in the Wikipedia article *is* identical to the Biblical text. Same words, same order. If you believe that there's a difference, then please articulate what difference you perceive, and we can teach you something. But you're not going to learn anything by repeating your claim over and over again when the rest of us can tell that it's false.